# How do I edit a global variable within a closure in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures

I am developing an app with Xcode and the Swift programming language. Keep in mind my app works closely with Firebase. I created a function to retrieve a parameter from Firebase based on a key.

```
// My global variables. 'ref' is my firebase database and 'returnValue' is the value I am trying to write to withing the closure.
var ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "accounts")
var returnValue: String = ""


func getParam(key: String) -> String {
    let index = defs.integer(forKey: "index")

    self.returnValue = "Failed retrieving parameter in getParam() function"

    self.ref.child("data").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        let data = snapshot.value! as! NSArray
        let dictionary = data[index] as! NSDictionary
        self.returnValue = String(describing: dictionary[key])
        print("returnValue:", self.returnValue) //First line in console
        return
    }
    return self.returnValue
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(getParam("status")) //Second line in console
}
```

Whenever I call this function I see this in the console:

returnValue: Optional(0) //*take in mind this is the output I am looking for in the second line*

Failed retrieving parameter in getParam() function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function). Your call is asynchronous so your `print` statement is executed before the data has been downloaded from firebase (and there is very little point in returning an instance property anyway)

Answer (score 0):

When you call observeSingleElement, it is run synchronously, meaning the current thread sends it off and ignores whatever it does.

```
return self.returnValue
```

and has nothing to do with the closure in observeSingleElement.  You could pass a closure to

```
func getParam(key: String, completion: (String) -> Void) {
    let data = snapshot.value! as! NSArray
    let dictionary = data[index] as! NSDictionary
    let returnValue = String(describing: dictionary[key]) ?? "Failed retrieving parameter in getParam() function"
    completion(returnValue)
 }
```